# C + cURL + SQLite - CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE breaks some things even not related to it

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535518/curl-c-segmentation-fault

I have to continue what I have written there. After some testing, I have found out why the order mattered. If I firstly run this: `curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpcode);` I think it breaks some things related to cookies and more. Anyway, I'm here to ask help for another problem caused by this. In this case, the order doesn't matter at all.

I have a SQLite handler opened. After running the above code `curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpcode);` the handler just gets broken. If I remove this code, everything works well, but I need the response code and I'm really interested in this issue. Anyway, if I initialize the handler after `CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE` it works, but I don't like it this way.

I made tests on both Debian 6 64-bit and Debian Wheezy 64-bit (libcurl4-openssl-dev 7.26.0-1 + libsqlite3-dev 3.7.13-1).

Any help is extremely appreciated. :D

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved everything. The problem was related to `httpcode`. Once I made it `long` (initially it was `int`) all started working well.

Thanks!